# Keyboard handler for moving in four directions

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I'm having trouble deciding if I should leave the `default: break;` in the switch statement or not. It does kinda show intent, i.e. that most keys are not handled, but it's also effectively useless code. I feel like it's clear enough anyway, but maybe being explicit is better?

```
function handleKeyDownEvent(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 87: // w
            player.dy = -50
            break
        case 65: // a
            player.dx = -50
            break
        case 83: // s
            player.dy = 50
            break
        case 68: // d
            player.dx = 50
            break
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

Maps seem to be the preferred way of doing this, instead of a `switch` statement. How does the `movement` map work with the corresponding `handleKeyUpEvent` which works the same way, except that it zeroes the `dx` or `dy` values?

Should I keep the `default: break;` or not?

Comment: Usually is a good practice to put a break sentence on every case. I was going to develop a bit more on why but I found [a post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/201777/break-on-default-case-in-switch) that resumes it quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is rather short, but can still be greatly improved.

---

> Should I keep the default: break; or not?

Do not keep it. Since you aren't doing anything for the `default` case, there is no point in having it. You can remove that entire thing.

---

### Map

In order to improve the readability of your code (and overall efficiency), I recommend creating a map that maps the key code values to the changes needed to be made to `dx` and `dy`. Here is what I mean:

```
var keyToChangeMap = {
    87: [0, -50], // [change in x, change in y]
    65: [-50, 0]
    ...
};
```

Now, you have an \$O(1)\$ method for finding out how to change the `dx` and `dy` values. This is also flexible: you can easily change the values that x and y change by, and you can easily add more keys to listen to.

Then, in your function, simply use the key code to get a value from the map:

```
function handleKeyDownEvent(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    if(keyToChangeMap.hasOwnProperty(keyCode)) {
        var change = keyToChangeMap[keyCode];
        player.dx += change[0];
        player.dy += change[1];
    }
}
```

---

### Magic numbers

You have some [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) in your code. It's pretty difficult to understand these numbers, so you should create constants to represent these values.

For example,

```
var W_KEY = 87;
var A_KEY = 65;
```

You don't even have to be that specific. You can do something like this:

```
var UP_KEY = 87;
var LEFT_KEY = 65;
```

which is even more readable.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think that `default:` would be noise.  It's obvious that this code makes no attempt to handle every possible keycode.

I suggest using a variant of @SirPython's suggestion to use a lookup table.  It can be written in a way that reminds you of the keyboard layout.

```
var MOVEMENT = {    /* W */ 87: { dy: -50 },
  /* A */ 65: { dx: -50 },              /* D */ 68: { dx: +50 },
                    /* S */ 83: { dy: +50 },
};

function handleKeyDownEvent(event) {
    var movement;
    if (movement = MOVEMENT[event.keyCode]) {
        player.dx += (movement.dx || 0);
        player.dy += (movement.dy || 0);
    }
}
```